# In java, multithread calling same method, how to get the sum of a parameter in this method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class like this

```
class A{
  private B b = new B();
  public void restore(){
    b.restoreTask();
  }
}

class B{
  public void restoreTask(){
    int taskcount = somenumber;
    for(int i = 0; i<taskcount; ++i){
      do something to all tasks
    }
  }
}
```

There will be multi threads calling A.restore(), so there may be multiple restoreTask() running, every restoreTask() have a taskcount of different value. How can I get the current sum of all taskcount parameter in restoreTask()?

Comment: do you mean that you need to count  all calling of  this line " do something to all tasks"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AtomicInteger` As counter because `AtomicInteger` is thread safe

```
class A{
      private B b = new B();
      public static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
      public void restore(){
        b.restoreTask();
      }
    }

    class B{
      public void restoreTask(){
        int taskcount = somenumber;
        A.count.addAndGet(taskcount);
        for(int i = 0; i<taskcount; ++i){
          do something to all tasks
        }
      }
    }
```

but please remember to join all thread before try to get the value of counter

Comment: How can I call A in B since B is a member of A?

Comment: And can I use AtomicInteger count in class B ?

Comment: No you can not use count  in class B because every B instance will has it is own count and and the counters will be isolated and it will not updated correctly.

Comment: count in A is static method and you can use it any where by using class name even in nested class

Answer (score 0):

```
class Counter{
  int a;
}

class A{
  private B b;
  public A(Counter counter) {
    b = new B(counter);
  }
  public void restore(){
    b.restoreTask();
  }
}

class B{
  public B(Counter counter) {
    this.counter = counter;
  }
  public void restoreTask(){
    int taskcount = somenumber;
    synchronized(counter) {
      ...
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<taskcount; ++i){
      do something to all tasks
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever you make changes in taskcount, you need to lock counter, change the value and release the lock.